# Getting LOCATIONS_ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE for gps after about an hour in tizen wearable application

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, tizen-studio

We have location tracking tizen wearable hybrid application. which scans gps location in every 10 minutes and sends to server.

We are able to scan location perfectly for almost 1 hours on gear s3 LTE version but after that it starts giving error LOCATIONS_ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, even if we never moved watch from same location.

if I go outside of home it wont be able to recover it from LOCATIONS_ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error.

We have following in Tizen manifest file(Service app):

We have following in config.xml file(Web app):

Thanks

Comment: Could you check manifest and config file ? Can't find them.

Answer (score 0):

LOCATIONS_ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE occurs when location service couldn't get the location details from satellite.

This will occur when your app places request to get new GPS location, and your device couldn't get proper GPS signal at the same time.